# Reading Binary Stream of a .docx file without apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, streaming, filestream

I am reading binary stream of a .docx file directly, to parse the piece table and to extract text from the file.

But some variables in FIB (FC/LCB pair) contains 0's from ox01A0 to ox01AF as bellow: (offset add's of FC and LCB are 0x01A2 and 0x01A6, respectively. and they are 32-bit int's)

01A0 to 01AF    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
                                                        |**_______**|**_______**|
                                                                   FC         LCB

I want to ask, what does it means when these variables have these vales? and is the file is corrupted?
ALso please guide me to do this.
thanks,

Comment: Also please tell me that whether .doc and .docx files have same format or not?

Comment: No they don't.  A docx file is a zip file.  A doc file is not.  You can find the specs for each via web search.

Comment: thanks for the information sir, do you have any material for these about their formats?